# Efficient indexing of date ranges across very large datasets

Tags: r, data.table

I have two very large related data frames with output data from depth loggers.

**EDIT: Easier data download for MWE:**

```
library(RCurl)
dives_log <- read.csv(text = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sebpardo/dive-data-mwe/master/dives_log.csv"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dives_summary <- read.csv(text = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sebpardo/dive-data-mwe/master/dives_summary.csv"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dives_log$Date <- as.POSIXct(dives_log$Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
dives_summary$Start <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
dives_summary$Bottom.Start <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Bottom.Start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
dives_summary$Ascent.Start <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Ascent.Start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
dives_summary$Ascent.End <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Ascent.End, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
```

The first one (`dives_log`) contains logger data every 10 seconds:

```
> head(dives_log)
                 Date Depth
1 2010-09-11 23:03:20   6.5
2 2010-09-11 23:03:30   6.5
3 2010-09-11 23:03:40   7.0
4 2010-09-11 23:03:50   7.0
5 2010-09-11 23:04:00   7.0
6 2010-09-11 23:04:10   0.0
> nrow(dives_log)
[1] 816036
```

while the second one (`dives_summary`) has a summary of the dive profiles with the start, bottom, and ascent times for every dive cycle recorded.

```
> head(dives_summary)
  Dive               Start        Bottom.Start        Ascent.Start          Ascent.End
1    1 2010-09-11 22:59:20 2010-09-11 23:03:20 2010-09-11 23:04:00 2010-09-11 23:04:10
2    2 2010-09-11 23:04:40 2010-09-11 23:04:50 2010-09-11 23:07:20 2010-09-11 23:08:30
3    3 2010-09-11 23:09:00 2010-09-11 23:13:00 2010-09-11 23:17:30 2010-09-11 23:18:00
4    4 2010-09-11 23:18:40 2010-09-11 23:19:00 2010-09-11 23:26:50 2010-09-11 23:27:20
5    5 2010-09-11 23:28:10 2010-09-11 23:28:50 2010-09-11 23:35:40 2010-09-11 23:36:20
6    6 2010-09-11 23:37:10 2010-09-11 23:37:30 2010-09-11 23:44:40 2010-09-11 23:45:30
> nrow(dives_summary)
[1] 12697
```

What I want to do is assign the dive number (`dives_summary$Dive`) and dive phase (bottom or ascent) to each *individual data point* (i.e. row) in `dives_log`. So far the way I'm doing this is by indexing the rows in `dives_log` that match the time range in each row of `dives_summary`:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dives_summary)) {  
  pos.bottom <- which(dives_log$Date >= dives_summary$Bottom.Start[i] & 
                        dives_log$Date <= dives_summary$Ascent.Start[i])
  pos.ascent <- which(dives_log$Date > dives_summary$Ascent.Start[i] & 
                        dives_log$Date <= dives_summary$Ascent.End[i])

  dives_log[pos.bottom, "Phase"] <- "bottom"
  dives_log[pos.ascent, "Phase"] <- "ascent"
  dives_log[pos.bottom, "Number"] <- dives_summary[i, "Dive"]
  dives_log[pos.ascent, "Number"] <- dives_summary[i, "Dive"]
}
```

This does the trick, but it is **extremely** slow given that for each one of the 12697 rows of `dives_summary`, the for loop has to check logical statement comparisons for multiple vectors that are 800k+ rows long:

```
> head(dives_log)
                 Date Depth  Phase Number
1 2010-09-11 23:03:20   6.5 bottom      1
2 2010-09-11 23:03:30   6.5 bottom      1
3 2010-09-11 23:03:40   7.0 bottom      1
4 2010-09-11 23:03:50   7.0 bottom      1
5 2010-09-11 23:04:00   7.0 bottom      1
6 2010-09-11 23:04:10   0.0 ascent      1
```

What would be the way to do this in a much faster way? I imagine this is doable using `data.table`, but I cannot wrap my head around how to vectorize the logical statements across two separate data frames. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could `melt` your summary to appear on two rows (one for bottom, one for ascent) and then do a non-equi join to do the assignment. It would be easier to show the details with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what @Frank meant by `melt`. Maybe he can illustrate better.

Here is a version of using non-equi joins.

```
#get to the bottom
dives_log[dives_summary, ':=' (
    Phase = 'bottom',
    Number = Dive
    ), on=.(Date >= Bottom_Start, Date <= Ascent_Start)]

#rise to the top
dives_log[dives_summary, ':=' (
    Phase = 'ascent',
    Number = Dive
), on=.(Date > Ascent_Start, Date <= Ascent_End)]
```

data:

```
dives_log <- fread('Date,Depth
"2010-09-11 23:03:20",6.5
"2010-09-11 23:03:30",6.5
"2010-09-11 23:03:40",7.0
"2010-09-11 23:03:50",7.0
"2010-09-11 23:04:00",7.0
"2010-09-11 23:04:10",0.0')[, 
    Date := as.POSIXct(Date)]

cols <- c("Start","Bottom_Start","Ascent_Start","Ascent_End")
dives_summary <- fread('Dive,Start,Bottom_Start,Ascent_Start,Ascent_End
1,"2010-09-11 22:59:20","2010-09-11 23:03:20","2010-09-11 23:04:00","2010-09-11 23:04:10"
2,"2010-09-11 23:04:40","2010-09-11 23:04:50","2010-09-11 23:07:20","2010-09-11 23:08:30"
3,"2010-09-11 23:09:00","2010-09-11 23:13:00","2010-09-11 23:17:30","2010-09-11 23:18:00"
4,"2010-09-11 23:18:40","2010-09-11 23:19:00","2010-09-11 23:26:50","2010-09-11 23:27:20"
5,"2010-09-11 23:28:10","2010-09-11 23:28:50","2010-09-11 23:35:40","2010-09-11 23:36:20"
6,"2010-09-11 23:37:10","2010-09-11 23:37:30","2010-09-11 23:44:40","2010-09-11 23:45:30"')[, 
    (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct), .SDcols=cols]
```

Comment: I got this to work on the MWE after changing variable names to match. While the other methods (including mine) take several minutes to run, this one takes a fraction of a second! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please edit the answer to have the correct variable names and show the `as.data.table` step so it works with the MWE and others can easily test it?

Comment: Most elegant solution to deal with large data.

Answer (score 0):

A `sqldf` based solution can be used in this situation to avoid `for-loop`. The approach is to first join 2 dataframes to first match the condition for `bottom` Phase and then `UNION` output with join to match condition for `ascent` phase.

```
# Data
dives_log <- read.table(text = "Date Depth
'2010-09-11 23:03:20'   6.5
'2010-09-11 23:03:30'   6.5
'2010-09-11 23:03:40'   7.0
'2010-09-11 23:03:50'   7.0
'2010-09-11 23:04:00'   7.0
'2010-09-11 23:04:10'   0.0", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

#Convert to POSIXct format
dives_log$Date <- as.POSIXct(dives_log$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


dives_summary <- read.table(text = "Dive   Start   Bottom_Start  Ascent_Start   Ascent_End
1 '2010-09-11 22:59:20' '2010-09-11 23:03:20' '2010-09-11 23:04:00' '2010-09-11 23:04:10'
2 '2010-09-11 23:04:40' '2010-09-11 23:04:50' '2010-09-11 23:07:20' '2010-09-11 23:08:30'
3 '2010-09-11 23:09:00' '2010-09-11 23:13:00' '2010-09-11 23:17:30' '2010-09-11 23:18:00'
4 '2010-09-11 23:18:40' '2010-09-11 23:19:00' '2010-09-11 23:26:50' '2010-09-11 23:27:20'
5 '2010-09-11 23:28:10' '2010-09-11 23:28:50' '2010-09-11 23:35:40' '2010-09-11 23:36:20'
6 '2010-09-11 23:37:10' '2010-09-11 23:37:30' '2010-09-11 23:44:40' '2010-09-11 23:45:30'",
 header = T, stringsAsFactor = F)

#convert columns to POSIXct format
dives_summary$Start <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Start, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dives_summary$Bottom_Start <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Bottom_Start, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dives_summary$Ascent_Start <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Ascent_Start, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dives_summary$Ascent_End <- as.POSIXct(dives_summary$Ascent_End, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


library(sqldf)

result <- sqldf("SELECT dives_log.*, 'bottom' as Phase, dives_summary.Dive as Number 
FROM dives_log, dives_summary 
WHERE dives_log.Date BETWEEN dives_summary.Bottom_Start AND  dives_summary.Ascent_Start
UNION 
SELECT dives_log.*, 'ascent' as Phase, dives_summary.Dive as Number 
FROM dives_log, dives_summary 
WHERE dives_log.Date > dives_summary.Ascent_Start AND
dives_log.Date <= dives_summary.Ascent_End")

result

#                 Date Depth  Phase Number
#1 2010-09-11 23:03:20   6.5 bottom      1
#2 2010-09-11 23:03:30   6.5 bottom      1
#3 2010-09-11 23:03:40   7.0 bottom      1
#4 2010-09-11 23:03:50   7.0 bottom      1
#5 2010-09-11 23:04:00   7.0 bottom      1
#6 2010-09-11 23:04:10   0.0 ascent      1
```

Comment: I attempted to run this with the sample dataset (I've edited the question so it's easier to download through R), but my computer freezes instantly. I imagine the `inner_join` using a dummy variable of two extremely large data frames (800k x 12k) is too much memory for my computer to handle.

Comment: @sebpardo Agree. The `inner_join` with dummy column needs huge memory in case of large table and its not very optimize either. I updated my answer to use `sqldf` which is easier to use and should be much faster than `for-loop` and `dplyr` based solution.

Comment: Add the argument `dbname = tempfile()` to the `sqldf` statement to cause it to use an external database rather than its default which is to do it in memory.  If that does not work try using a different back end database.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loops is usually very slow. I always try to replace them with  `lapply`:

```
new_cols <- lapply(1:nrow(dives_summary), function(i) {
    pos.bottom <- which(dives_log$Date >= dives_summary$Bottom.Start[i] & 
                            dives_log$Date <= dives_summary$Ascent.Start[i])
    pos.ascent <- which(dives_log$Date > dives_summary$Ascent.Start[i] & 
                            dives_log$Date <= dives_summary$Ascent.End[i])

    phase <- c(rep('bottom', length(pos.bottom)), rep('ascent', length(pos.ascent)))
    number <- rep(i, length(c(pos.bottom, pos.ascent)))
    list(Phase=phase, Number=number)
})

dives_log$Phase <- unlist(sapply(new_cols, `[[`, 1)) # Get Phase
dives_log$Number <- unlist(sapply(new_cols, `[[`, 2)) # Get Number
```

In my computer, it takes 2.5 minutes. If you do it in parallel (I use `mclapply` from the package `parallel`) it takes 52 seconds with 4 cores.

Comment: I don't think the `for` loop is the bottle neck here, but instead the `which` statements that are applied over the 800k+ rows of `dives_log`.